# Control where command line R sends the browser window?

Tags: r, command-line, headless

I'm trying to run R from the command line. During my program I invoke a function from `gmailr` that requires browser authentication with google.

How can I send the browser its supposed to open to a local address so I can complete the authentication?

Comment: `browseURL()` opens a new window/tab in the system default browser with the specified URL. Does that help?

Comment: no, nothing opens

Comment: if `local_address` had the URL to your "local address" `browseURL(local_address)` should open that URL; like `browseURL("https://stackoverflow.com")`. Can you add to the question what command from the gmailr package this is about?

Comment: Its not really relevant about gmailr, this question essentially applies to running R in any setting where a webpage is not automatically opened with `browseURL()` or code that would otherwise open a webpage.

Comment: So to clarify, running R at the terminal in linux, `browseURL()` does not work

Comment: In your question your say "trying to run R from the command line" and by that you mean that you are doing that on a remote machine? If yes, please make that more explicit in your question and describe how you access the remote machine. If R runs on a remote machine you could maybe do something with an SSH tunnel or another route could be to see if you can create an auth token locally and then store that on the remote machine.

Comment: No, its my own linux box, with Terminal open. Fine with opening the browser window in linux directly if it would just pop up. I was just assuming the answer involves serving the page to some local address and I open my web browser to that address.

Comment: The auth file is stored locally and can be accessed, its just that it also prompts you for a regular google login